# Sharepoint - Where are .cs files stored?

Tags: sharepoint, asp.net

I have a file called webpart.cs which is called by one of my masterpages in Sharepoint, where are those files stored on the Server?

Comment: SharePoint by default doesn't refer any cs files, Can brief more about where exactly you found this reference , is that a custom master page etc?

Comment: Perhaps it's a typo and should be webpart.css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your master page is referencing a .css (and not a .cs) file, those are typically in /_catalogs/masterpage - but that entirely depends on the master page, and from HOW it's referencing the .css it should be fairly straightforward to figure out where the file lives.

There's no way of referencing a .cs file directly, you can reference the namespace and the assembly, but not the .cs file. Or are you talking about finding the .cs file that built  the assembly ? If so, reflector is your friend if this isn't your assembly...